# Placing adoptee in family tree when What Are The Odds cannot help?

Tags: autosomal-dna, adoption

I am trying to figure out where an adoptee fits in my family tree. I know he are is related on his paternal side, since his maternal side has been identified and is not related to my family. I have many cM matches from GEDmatch and AncestryDNA. I combined them with our family tree and put them into What Are The Odds? (WATO):

[image: WATO tree]

("Names" followed by "A" indicate that measure came from AncestryDNA.) Every hypothesis I could place on the tree had zero probability. You can [play with the tree yourself](https://dnapainter.com/tools/probability/view/e1b0aa3c1adf5a25).

The problem seems to step from the adoptee having matches in the 1C1R range with people in our family tree who are too far apart for anyone to be a 1C1R (or the equivalent) with all of them. My hypothesis is that there must have been some intermarriage between different branches of the family tree. I haven't found any in my genealogy, but if any of you are savvy enough to tell me where to look or give me any other advice, that would help me. I know a Y-DNA result would be useful, but none is available.

Another complication involves the node NE. There is also a relationship through the spouse of NE, but I don't think I can represent that on WATO. Specifically, NE's husband's brother's grandchild (bc. 1940) is a 220 cM match.

Comment: Hi Seeker, just to be sure, the cM numbers you have entered are the match between the adoptee and those matches, not you and those matches?

Comment: There are a lot of strong DNA matches here but they are all in an annoying range that could be lots of different relationships. I can see why you're struggling, this is quite the puzzle.

Comment: @HarryVervet Yes, I just now checked again. I did make a minor cM mistranscription and replaced the image, but it's not a significant difference.

Comment: What is the relationship through the spouse of NE? I've identified one possible relationship but that could change things significantly.

Comment: And one final question - what is the year of birth and death of JHP, as well as the birth year of the adoptee?

Comment: @HarryVervet I've added approximate birth years and a link to the tree so you can play with it. I'll have to get back to you tomorrow about the other relationship. FYI, I was wrong about the adoptee being old and the father probably being dead, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, although it rules out the one hypothesis I thought might work. Will have to have another think on this...

Comment: You can't put NE's spouse in the same WATO, but you can start another one.

Comment: Is it just adoptee that matches the JHP branch and the GWP branch really well or do other family members also have equally strong matches on both branches?

Answer (score 2):

I started by eliminating the GWP branch of the tree and finding the best fit to the JHP branch. This is shown [here](https://dnapainter.com/tools/probability/view/fc3499ec64e02f92). One hypothesis is 4 generations removed from PJPEH and has a score of 4,923,736,333. You can then keep the GWP branch and eliminate the JHP branch to get [this](https://dnapainter.com/tools/probability/view/d9b68a14afef16ab). The best hypothesis there has a score of 11 and is 3 generations removed from PJPEH. The GWP branch and the JHP branch are not consistent with each other for some reason. Maybe adoptee is related to the two branches in a different way or maybe there is half relationship that is not reflected in the tree or something like that.

I would start with Hypothesis 4 on the JHP branch as the best guess. Does adoptee match other branches of NE's spouses line?

**Updated:**

Based on the updated information about the match to NE's spouse's line, I put in as an hypothesis a half brother to NG shown [here](https://dnapainter.com/tools/probability/view/fc3499ec64e02f92). It shows good odds. Is that possible?

Comment: That is very telling. So very likely adoptee is a descendant of NE and spouse. How about spouses of GA and WL? And could GA and WL have a sibling?